# VM instance disappeared

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a VM Instance on Google Cloud, and installed created a website on it. yesterday when trying to access the site it was gone. please see the error message attached

[Project Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUOGN.png)

Comment: What steps have you tried to solve this problem. Your question has no details, so we can only guess. Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tip: check if the IP address changed. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses

Comment: The VM Instance is no longer in my console. I checked my billing account an all are set properly, The DNS Zone is gone. The IP was set on static. If I could recover the data I could build another server

Comment: Cloud Logging audit logs will show you when those resources were deleted and by which identity. There is nothing we can do. Open a Google Cloud Support ticket. That does require a paid support agreement.